# iOS Live Activity timer with automatic update

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit, widgetliveactivity

i need to create timer-like with live activities. I noticed that system clock app can start live activity when timer is started. In addition, value inside change every second.

In official Apple documentation only ways to update live activities are Attributes struct or push notification. I asked to me if timer send push notification every second but i think this is impossible.

I try to use ProgressView or TimelineView inside live activity but anything change.

Anyone can help me?

This is an example of my expectation
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1CsG.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
Text(Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 10, to: Date(), style: .timer)
```